# Iptables config for BubbleUpnpServer

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

SUDDENLY my bubbleupnpserver is not able to connect on the port 58050 for http and 58051 for https. Yesterday was working, no changes on the server, puff, today no working anymore. Maybe it's fail2ban?
Errors:

```
HTTP: ERROR: Cannot connect. Check that the public host name is valid and that port 58050 is opened on your router

HTTPS: ERROR: Cannot connect. Check that the public host name is valid and that port 58051 is opened on your router
```

Here's the output of iptables:

```
 sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             ns375259.ip-5-196-88.eu  tcp dpt:58051
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             ns375259.ip-5-196-88.eu  tcp dpt:58050
f2b-sshd   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports s                         sh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

As suggested, on netstat -tulpn i've found 2 entries with this ports, and it looks like this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58050           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1455/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58051           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1455/java
```

Comment: Your firewall doesn't actually block anything. Is your service running?

Comment: yes because i can access it remotely via web browser. I don't understand why yestarday was working and now it's dead without changing configurations server side

Comment: if fail2ban is the problem you should see something in your fail2ban log. `/var/log/fail2ban.log` Check with `telnet hostname port` if you can get a connection from the client. check with `netstat -tulpn` on the server if the application is listening to the ports.

Comment: I've added the netstat -tulpn related to this ports. Any help appreciated

Comment: SUDDENLY Has started working again... maybe was a dns issue on the datacenter? I'm puzzled.